Visa free entry to Philippines for Indians having Japan work visa
As per the GOVPH website (GOVPH Website Link), Indians who has multiple-entry visa or permanent residence permit in Japan can travel visa free to Philippines.
I have a Japan work visa. But in the stamped Visa, it is mentioned as Single Entry. When I came to Japan, the emigration officer pasted a "Landing Permission Slip" which is valid until November, 2026. Also get a Japanese Resident Card which also valid until November, 2026.
My question is, am I eligible for visa free entry to Philippines with this Japan visa? Because my visa is Single Entry Type and I don't have permanent residence permit as the Resident card is valid for 3 yrs only. (I already went out of Japan and came back to Japan on the same visa. For this, while leaving Japan we need to fill in a re-entry permit, and we can come back to Japan anytime within one year).
Is anyone travelled to Philippines with a single entry Japanese work visa?

Your resident card is equivalent of a multiple entry visa. You can enter Philippines without additional visa.
I had entered Philipines using a resident card of Singapore (S-Pass), which was valid for two years. I didn't had any issues and they didn't even ask where I am going to stay or when I am going back. A person working legally in Japan/Singapore has very little incentive to illegally live or work in Philippines.

Thank you for the info. Let me try and mark this answer as accepted if I go through the immigration.
